# How to compute modulo of a hash?

Tags: dataset, bigdata, sampling, randomized-algorithms

Let's say that I have a set of users in my database, that have GUIDs as their IDs. I use `xxhash` to generate fixed-length hashes for each value, so that I can then proceed to "bucketizing" them and being able to do random sampling with the help of the modulo function.

That said, if I have a hash such as `367b50760441849e`, I want to be able to use `hash % 20 == 0` to randomly pick 5% of the population (*hence, 20 "buckets"*). This is the approach that is used in Kusto [`hash()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/hashfunction) with a modulo argument.

With this in mind, what is the approach that should be used to calculate an integer value from the hash, so that I can calculate the modulo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any good hash will be uniformly distributed, which means that you can assume a uniform distribution when you apply modulo `n`, as long as $n < 2^{M/2}$, where M is the number of bits in your hash, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/21010). So for SHA1-32 you would at most modulo by $2^{16}$.

There is no approach to calculating an integer value; what you have there is an hexadecimal representation of a hash, you just need to convert it to a numeric type if you obtained it as a string. `XXH32() and XXH64()` both already produce an unsigned int output.